# Pandas compare all values of a column with different DataFrame and return column name (of a dif. DataFrame) where value matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to assign category per row of a dataset based on matching keywords from other dataset.

1. I compare df_ONE['columnname'] to every value of df_TWO
2. and if matching value found use column name of df_TWO where this value is located as a cell value of new column in df_ONE.

With example below, all the values of a new string would be non-sport (column name of df_TWO where the value is found)

df_ONE

```
Heroes      The Punisher        
Heroes      The Punisher        
Heroes      Human Torch - 1     
Heroes      Man Thing           
Heroes      Medusa              
Heroes      Mr. Fantastic       
Movies-TV   Star Wars           
Movies-TV   Star Wars
```

df_TWO

```
         sport  non_sport   gaming
0     baseball  movies-tv  pokemon
1   basketball      music   yugioh
2     football     people    magic
3       hockey    history   gaming
4       soccer     heroes      NaN
5       racing        NaN      NaN
6       boxing        NaN      NaN
7         golf        NaN      NaN
8          mma        NaN      NaN
9   multisport        NaN      NaN
10      tennis        NaN      NaN
11   wrestling        NaN      NaN
12       poker        NaN      NaN
```

would be nice to have this result:

```
Heroes      The Punisher        non-sport
Heroes      The Punisher        non-sport
Heroes      Human Torch - 1     non-sport
Heroes      Man Thing           non-sport
Heroes      Medusa              non-sport
Heroes      Mr. Fantastic       non-sport
Movies-TV   Star Wars           non-sport
Movies-TV   Star Wars           non-sport
```

I've tried to adopt following solutions but had no luck.

- keywords.columns[keywords.eq('heroes').any()]
- (keywords == 'pokemon').idxmax(axis=1)[0]

into something like

- df[new_column] = df[category_column].isin(keywords).any()

Comment: I assume that there might be a better approach all together, like storing df_TWO in three lists instead of one dataframe.

Comment: or even just a dict: `{"baseball": "sport", "basketball": "sport", ..., "heroes": "non-sport", ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reshape your second dataframe.  You can do this with `melt` pretty easily.

Here is an example of what the melted df looks like:

```
    col_match   genre
0   sport   baseball
1   sport   basketball
2   sport   football
3   sport   hockey
4   sport   soccer
5   sport   racing
```

So you can use the melted df to join the original on the genre.  Be sure to lowercase your genre column in the first df.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'genre': ['Heroes',  'Heroes',  'Heroes',  'Heroes',  'Heroes',  'Heroes',  'Movies-TV',  'Movies-TV'],
    ' title': ['The Punisher',  'The Punisher',  'Human Torch - 1',  'Man Thing',  'Medusa',  'Mr. Fantastic',  'Star Wars',  'Star Wars']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'sport': ['baseball',  'basketball',  'football',  'hockey',  'soccer',  'racing',  'boxing',  'golf',  'mma',  'multisport',  'tennis',  'wrestling',  'poker'],
    'non_sport': ['movies-tv',  'music',  'people',  'history',  'heroes',  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan, np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan],
    'gaming': ['pokemon',  'yugioh',  'magic',  'gaming',  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan]})

df['genre'] = df['genre'].str.lower()

df.merge(df2.melt(value_vars=df2.columns, var_name='col_match', value_name='genre'), on='genre')
```

Output

```
       genre            title  col_match
0     heroes     The Punisher  non_sport
1     heroes     The Punisher  non_sport
2     heroes  Human Torch - 1  non_sport
3     heroes        Man Thing  non_sport
4     heroes           Medusa  non_sport
5     heroes    Mr. Fantastic  non_sport
6  movies-tv        Star Wars  non_sport
7  movies-tv        Star Wars  non_sport
```